# How to make a multidimensional array from a normal array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

If i had an array of lets say 15 elements is there anyway for me to make it into a 2d array having it 5x3?
Or if i had a string with 15 letters would it be possible to make it into a 2d array having it 5x3?

This is what i have(using variables but using 5 as a and 3 as b in console)

```
    void finishMap(string map, int a, int b)
{
    string finalMap[a][b];
    for(int i = 0; b>i; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; a>x; x++)
        {
            finalMap[a][b] += {{map[x]}, {i}};
        }
    }
}
```

Also pretty new to c++ so if you see anything i shouldn't be please tell me :3

Comment: C-style arrays must have dimension known at compile-time in C++; you can't go `string finalMap[a][b];`

Comment: @MattMcNabb you can go `string finalMap[a][b];` but indeed it does not do what he thinks.

Comment: @bolov you can't in Standard C++, some compilers have a questionable extension for runtime-sized arrays

Comment: @MattMcNabb you are wright, I got hanged up in the fact that `string s[][]` is not a table of chars. Completely missed the runtime-size aspect of it, even if your comment clearly stated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using char arrays (c strings) in my answer because I think they are useful to illustrate how arrays work - and thre really isn't a point in using std::string in your case. `std::string` hides a lot of the underlying nuts and bolts so I would generally recommend to play around with C strings first to understand how `std::string` works. Also, check out this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

A 2-dimensional array has the same memory layout as a 1-d array. In terms of memory layout, `char[3][5]` is the same as `char[3*5]` is the same as `char[15]`. You can use a 1-d array as a 2-d array using `char[column+row*width]`. The only difference if you use subscripts is that the compiler remembers how many dimensions there are and will do the whole `column+row*width` calculation for you.

Take this example:

```
char temp[5] = "abcd"; //need 5 for string termination char `\0`

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    std::cout << temp[i];
}        
std::cout << "\n\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        std::cout << temp[j+2*i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Will print:

```
abcd

ab
cd
```

Comment: doesn't really help me in terms of making a multi dim array... I'm suppose to have a map overlay stored in the 2d array...

Comment: Did what i asked in the original question, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always access an array in *strides*. Here's a possible example using templates to restride a 1D array as a 2D array:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N1, unsigned int N2>
struct strider
{
    using array_type = T[N1 * N2];

    array_type & data_;

    Strider(array_type & data) : data_(data) {}

    T & operator()(std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2)
    {
        return data_[i1 * N2 + i2];
    }
};

template <unsigned int N1, unsigned int N2, T>
strider<T, N1, N2> stride(T (&a)[N1, N2]) { return {a}; }
```

Usage:

```
int a[15] = {};

strider<int, 3, 5> s(a);
s(1, 2) = 20;
assert(a[7] == 20);

stride<5, 3>(a)(4, 2) = 10;
assert(a[14] == 10);
```

I've overloaded `operator()` for the strided access, since unlike `operator[]` it can have arbirary signatures.

With some more work you could make the rank of the strided view variadic.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this would work with variables

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `reinterpret_cast`. Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef char mtrx[5][3];

int main(){
   char data[15] = "Some String";
   mtrx &m = *reinterpret_cast<mtrx*>(&data);
   m[1][2] = '*';
   cout << data << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how would i go about adding stuff into the 2d array?

Comment: @3rdaccountQQ if I correctly understand the question, You can change content of `data` or `m` ( `data[5]='x'` is the same as `m[1][2]='x'` ), they both refer to the same memory, just don't go out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so i used something a bit different then what i mentioned. What i did was have the user enter 3 lines of 5 length letters, which i figured out how to add into the 2d array. If your having the same issue as me, heres my code:

```
int main()
{
    string path;
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    string finalMap[a][b];

    for(int i = 0; b>i; i++){
        cin >> path;
        for(int x = 0; a>x; x++){
            finalMap[x][i] = (path[x]);
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; b>x; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; a>y; y++)
        {
            cout << finalMap[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for trying tho, really appreciate it ^.-

Comment: Note that the expression `finalMap[x][i]` is evaluated similar to `finalMap[x*b + i]`, which means that you are accessing your array column by column. Modern hardware does not like this, it may mean a lot of additional cache misses, which can result in a significant performance degradation. So it's advisable to exchange the order of coordinates: replace `finalMap[a][b]` by `finalMap[b][a]`, and do the same with the other two lines that access `finalMap`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it ^.-

Comment: @3rdaccountQQ I think `string finalMap[a][b];` can be replaced with `char finalMap[a][b];`, because now You are declaring something like 3D array, but using just first element of 3rd dimmension.

Comment: @kestasx thanks, but is there a difference between string usage and char usage? does it have anything to do with preformance or is there another reason as to why?

Comment: Kestasx is right, the data could be stored in a 2D char array, and it would be much faster: the `string` class allocates a buffer under the hood to hold the string data. That allocation has significant overhead, both in terms of time (ca. 250 CPU cycles) and space (usually an allocation requires at least four pointers worth of storage). In this example, the allocation overhead easily dwarves the overhead of the wrong coodinate order. CC: @kestasx

Comment: Won't repeat what @cmaster has written above. I think You should take _gordonk_ answer and get a solid understanding how arrays work in C and C++. Your current answer dosn't match the original question, because there is no full-size array to transform.